# Python: EXE crashes on start

Tags: python, exe

I've been trying to turn my program into an exe and been running into some issues. It works perfectly when run in the programming environment (PyCharm) but when I turn it into an exe and try to run it it crashes immediately on launch (when it should keep a console instance up to show it is still running and log what it is doing).

I've gone through my script (commenting out sections) bit by bit to see where this error is cropping up and it seems that the program crashes whenever these two modules are imported:

```
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

The following code is an example of an endless print code I wrote that also crashes in the same way when including these imports:

```
import os
import time

import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello")
```

When I comment out the imports the program functions as intended:

```
import os
import time

# import requests
# from dotenv import load_dotenv

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello")
```

I'm at a loss for why including these libraries through import is causing the python compiler to flip out.

Note: The exe is generated in the PyCharm environment using through the following terminal command for pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Hello.py
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

---

I ran my cmd (windows) with the command "pip freeze". This is what I got:
[Windows CMD freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtMdn.png)

When I ran it on my pycharm terminal I got this: [PyCharm Terminal freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enflf.png)

Tried running on the windows command line using command "py {name.py}" and got the following two errors:

1.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Leland Fowler\Documents\Programming Projects\AirTable\XML WatchDog\WatchDog2.py", line 8, in 
> import Airtable_API_Handler
> File "C:\Users\Leland Fowler\Documents\Programming Projects\AirTable\XML WatchDog\Airtable_API_Handler.py", line 17, in
>
> import requests
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

2. 

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Leland Fowler\Documents\Programming Projects\AirTable\XML WatchDog\Hello.py", line 5, in 
> import dotenv
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv

I then tried to run install using pip (python -m pip install requests python-dotenv) and got the following message:

> Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (2.27.1) Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in
> c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (0.19.2) Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in
> c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (from requests) (1.26.8) Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5
> in c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (from requests) (3.3) Requirement already satisfied:
> certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (from requests) (2021.10.8) Requirement already satisfied:
> charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\leland
> fowler\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
> (from requests) (2.0.10) WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4;
> however, version 21.3.1 is available. You should consider upgrading
> via the 'C:\Users\Leland
> Fowler\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
> -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Now I'm confused because my system seems to be telling me that I have these modules installed but they don't show up on my freeze and seem to fail to load into my program...

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Does changing `from dotenv import load_dotenv` to `import dotenv` (and later `dotenv.load_dotenv`) works?

Comment: @James, I don't see any error on the cmd I launched it from. It's like it completed the script but didn't do anything that it did when I ran it through the programming environment...

Comment: @enzo, nope changing the import syntax didn't seem to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely due environments in python which seem to be really sketchy for beginners
run following command :

```
pip freeze
```

it will show all modules installed within the environment of your terminal which may differ from one in Pycharm

note that exe is more like a binary form of your code its not ran and errors wont stop the compiler (not in every case)

after running command "pip freeze" check if module "dotenv" is in list or not

if not run command

```
pip install dotenv
```

then build exe with :

```
pyinstaller --onefile {nameOfYourPythonFileWithNoCurlyBraces}
```

it will fix the problem if not try running your file with command

windows:

```
py {nameOfYourPythonFileWithNoCurlyBraces}
```

mac/linux:

```
python3 {nameOfYourPythonFileWithNoCurlyBraces}
or
python {nameOfYourPythonFileWithNoCurlyBraces}
```

example:

```
py Home.py
python3 Home.py
python Home.py
```

send the error message

EDITS:

module request is built in within python and is created after you install python it self

delete python and install newest version from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1-amd64.exe) will be fixed for sure

Comment: Ok I think you're right on the nose here. I've updated my OP with the details you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This might also help some people running into this issue: Installing libraries in PyCharm is not the same as installing those libraries on the machine itself.  Be sure to use pip to install all the libraries your project needs, that way PyInstaller can locate them and include them in your executable.